# What does this bivariate homogeneous equation definition mean?

Tags: functions, cryptography

I am starting out with cryptanalysis, and one of the problems is defined as:

> In this problem, we consider the case of a single bivariate homogeneous equation,i.e., an equationF(x,y) = 0 of degree D where F is of the form:
> $$F(x,y) = \sum_{i=0}^{D} F_ix^iy^{D-i}$$

I can see that $x^iy^{D-1}$ in the summation stands for degree $D$ polynomial, but I don't get what $F_i$ is for. The question is in the context of bivariate homogeneous equations in prime files/ integer ring.

Comment: Is it that $F_i$ denotes the coefficients?

Comment: Yes, coefficients in a ring if polynomials in 2 vars $x,y.$ You mention integer ring, so my guess is the $F_i$ are integers.

Comment: So what could possible equations look like?

Comment: Well just make some choices for the coefficients. Like if $D=2$ it could be $3x^2+5xy-2y^2.$ Note using $0$ coefficients can drop some terms, like say $-7xy+123y^2$ it being understood coeff of $x^2$ is $0.$

Comment: Note in my examples I just gave $F(x,y).$ To get an *equation* must say $F(x,y)=0$ by their definition.